# Изменение данных в столбце ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

у меня есть таблица `city`. В ней есть столбцы `name` , `id` , `address_number`. Как сделать так, чтобы в столбце `address_number` остались только номера телефонов и удалить все адреса?

| name | id | address_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hamburg | 03000 | aachenerStr 128, num. +49(xxx)xxxxxxxxx |

Comment: формат известен точно? можно воспользоваться регуляркой, это медленно, но если это разовая акция удаления - вполне себе вариант.

Comment: Может, разумнее всё-таки создать дополнительно поле под номер телефона, и скопировать туда номера из поля адреса? удаление любой информации в общем неправильное мероприятие...

Comment: @Akina я создал дубликат столбца и назвал его numbers. У меня строк больше 1000

Comment: Покажите несколько значений поля (желательно охватить все возможные шаблоны).

Comment: 45497, city Hamburg, Aachenerstr, house 45, num. +49(176)744-36-44 из стобца adress_number

Comment: @Akina А можете показать как будет выглядеть ваш пример, где нужно скопировать только номера из поля

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков не понял вашего вопроса

Comment: Простите, имел неосторожность подумать что вы здесь чтоб разобраться в вопросе, а не получить готовое решение на блюдечке :) если хотите разбираться смотрите в сторону регулярных выражений, в MSSQL с ними не просто, но и не так и сложно.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что все значения, из которых надо извлекать телефонный номер, строго соответствуют единственному показанному значению, и для выделения телефонного номера достаточно просто отделить подстроку после последнего пробела?

Comment: @Akina Да, *код города*, *адрес*, и обязательно слово num. и +49(xxx)xxxxxxxx иногда 00(xxx)xxxxxxx

Comment: [STRING_SPLIT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). В качестве сепаратора - `num.`

Answer (score 0):

Если формат фиксированный, т.е. в твоём случае номер занимает 17 символов с конца, то можно так:

```
UPDATE city
SET address_number = RIGHT(address_number, 17)
```

Но для начала проверь, как получается:

```
SELECT RIGHT(address_number, 17)
FROM city
```

Если формат не фиксированный, то можно попробовать найти индекс символа "+"(если все номера начинаются с плюса) и выбрать подстроку функцией SUBSTRING с индекса символа "+" до конца строки. Для определения индекса используй функцию CHARINDEX:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('+', address_number)
```

А лучше создай дополнительный столбец и в него запиши номер. При необходимости исходный столбец можно будет удалить..